# How to avoid blank candles showing 0, 0, 0, 0 in highstock candlestick chart on dynamic update with shift

Tags: highcharts

I have discontinuous series of dynamic data to be plotted on a candle-stick chart. 
Is there a way to suppress blank candles ?

http://jsfiddle.net/nitincool4urchat/3v61f8v7/12/

In the above fiddle, the interval b/w consecutive clicks on the AddPoints button, shows blank candles. (not 100% sure if this is the reason for blank candles)

Also, this happens only with dynamic data, for data already shown on chart while loading in discontinuous intervals works fine.

Also, unable to figure out why but adding new points removes existing candles. The buttons for time-frames also don't work.

```
$(function () {

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global : {
            useUTC : true
        }
    });

    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
                        plotOptions: {
                            candlestick: {
                                color: 'red',
                                upColor: 'green'
                            }
                        },
                        rangeSelector: {
                            buttons: [
                                {
                                    count: 1,
                                    type: 'minute',
                                    text: '1M'
                                }
                                ,
                                {
                                    count: 5,
                                    type: 'minute',
                                    text: '5M'
                                },
                                {
                                    type: 'all',
                                    text: 'All'
                                }
                            ],
                            inputEnabled: false,
                            selected: 0
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Live data'
                        },
                        exporting: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        series: [
                            {
                                type: 'candlestick',
                                name: 'Trade Data',
                                data:[
                                    [Date.now()-5000,300 + Math.random()*100,300 + Math.random()*100,300 + Math.random()*100,300 + Math.random()*100],
                                     [Date.now()-3000,300 + Math.random()*100,300 + Math.random()*100,300 + Math.random()*100,300 + Math.random()*100],
                                     [Date.now()-1000,300 + Math.random()*100,300 + Math.random()*100,300 + Math.random()*100,300 + Math.random()*100],
                                    [Date.now(),300 + Math.random()*100,300 + Math.random()*100,300 + Math.random()*100,300 + Math.random()*100],
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    });

    $('#button').click(function () {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
            i = 0,
            series = chart.series[0];

        for (i; i < 1; i += 1) {
            series.addPoint([Date.now(),300 + Math.random()*100,300 + Math.random()*100,300 + Math.random()*100,300 + Math.random()*100], true, true);
        }
    });
});
```

Disabling shifting works. Unable to understand the reason though!

http://jsfiddle.net/nitincool4urchat/ev64enwh/3/

Comment: best way is to pre-filter the data as part of your data extraction/parsing, and don't send the kind of values you want to exclude in the first place.

Comment: data is already filtered, there are no null or zero values. I'm unable to understand why highstock is plotting empty candles.

Comment: "Also, unable to figure out why but adding new points removes existing candles"..."Disabling shifting works. Unable to understand the reason though!"  Well, that is exactly what the shift property does. It keeps a constant number of data points on the chart by shifting the first data point off each time a new data point is added. The buttons don't work because there isn't enough data for them to do anything.

Comment: @jlbriggs thanks for clearing what shifting does, I earlier thought it shifts automatically to bring the new candle to viewport. Now, the only remaining doubt is why the newly added candle is blank most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the API before using!

`When shift is true, one point is shifted off the start of the series as one is appended to the end. Use this option for live charts monitoring a value over time.`

So it is because of `shift` that your previous data is lost.

The problem with the zero data is because of the `datetime` format. So if you hit the button for example 3 seconds after the chart has loaded, you will get about three zero data and then a normal data is displayed. If you hit the button 5 seconds after loading the data, you will get near 5 zero data. But if you hit the button every second in a fixed interval you will always get your data. Again it's because of the shift property. I advise using the last `data`'s x value for adding the new data. Replace:

```
Date.now()
```

with this:

```
chart.series[0].data[3].x + Math.random()*1000
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ev64enwh/4/